# Projecteuler 3 - largest prime number

Tags: c

I'm curious why this code doesn't find the largest prime factor.
I can't find the mathematic and/or logic mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compute( int input ) {
    int biggest_primefactor = 1;

    while(input > biggest_primefactor) {
        int i = 2;
        while(input%i != 0) i++; /* find factor, which is a primefactor */
        input /= i;
        if( i > biggest_primefactor) biggest_primefactor = i;
    }
    return biggest_primefactor;
}

void main () {
    unsigned long long int input = 600851475143;
    printf("%d", compute( input ));
}
```

Output is 1

Comment: Your second while loop doesn't have brackets

Comment: The logic mistake is that you are trying to fit a too large number into an int. If you'd debug your code you'd quickly find out what's wrong here. Right now you are computing the biggest prime factor for -443946297.

Comment: Also, [proper compiler settings would tell you that your code is wrong before even running it](https://godbolt.org/g/sRm7Js).